# Why does #!/usr/bin/env show "$@" as 1?

Tags: bash

If I have test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$@"
```

`bash test.sh` results in `1`

Any idea why the result is 1? Also, why shebang to env instead of directly to bash?

UPDATE: Sorry, I missed some code, which now having that, it makes sense.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
main() {
  echo ${1:-1}
}
main "$@"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

You should test `echo "$@"` outside the script. It will show `1` if you had previously typed `set 1`, or the results of any previous positional parameter `set` command (including in the start-up scripts).

Note that `bash test.sh` runs `test.sh` as a `source` (`.`) file, and any `#!` line is ignored. To act on `!#` you would need:

```
bash -c test.sh
```

As for why `env` is specified, I have no idea, unless it was added as a place-holder: it would have an effect if it included one or more environment specifications. For example, the following would specify `bash` to run with a custom start-up file:

```
!#/usr/bin/env BASH_ENV=BashStart bash
...
```

Another reason, suggested by Attie's answer, is that in OSX `bash` by default is not in `/bin/`, but `env` is in `/usr/bin/`, as in Linux, so `!#/usr/bin/env bash` allows `bash` to be specified as the shell in a script which will run in either Linux or OSX.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some code. Thank you for the env explanation.

Comment: The omitted shows, as Attie's answer explains, that you were not expanding `"$@"` in the `echo` command, but `$1` with the default of `1` when not set.

Answer (score 0):

The "*missing code*" is very significant.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
  echo ${1:-1}
}

main "$@"
```

Here, we are calling the `main` function, and providing `"${@}"` (i.e: all of our arguments, maintaining separation).

When `${@}` expands to nothing (i.e: the script was invoked with no arguments), the `main()` is called with *no* arguments, and thus the `${1:-1}` inside the `main()` function will have a special effect, as per the "[*Parameter Substitution*](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)" semantics.

Specifically `${parameter:-default}` will expand to the value of `${parameter}` if it is declared and not-NULL, or `default` if it is undeclared or NULL. Note that `${parameter:-default}` behaves subtly different to `${parameter-default}`.

> `${parameter-default}` and `${parameter:-default}` are almost equivalent. The extra `:` makes a difference only when parameter has been declared, but is null.

So the `${1:-1}` will either expand to the first argument given, or default to `1`:

```
$ ./script.sh
1
```

```
$ ./script.sh test
test
```

---

The use of `/usr/bin/env` in the shebang allows us to "*use `bash` as the interpreter*" without giving the full path to `bash`... `env` will search the current environment's `${PATH}` and use the first matching candidate for us. The shebang requires an absolute path to the interpreter, and we are able to get around this limitation by using `env`.

This is very common with Python scripts, as the interpreter can be in a number of locations - though often `/usr/bin/python`, this supports things like [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) too.

See "[*Why do people write the #!/usr/bin/env python shebang on the first line of a Python script?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt)" for more discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the note on `env`: is it in `/usr/bin/` in OSX? If so, it provides a MAC-compatible way of specifying `bash` as the program to run for a script.

Comment: I don't know, but it [looks like it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297535)!

Comment: Thanks for the link: I've extended my answer to include this as a possible reason for the use of `env`.